# Batch extract thumbnails with ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, batch-file, png

I need to batch extract thumbnail pic from hundreds of .mpg files using the following bat code, which works like a charm, but the only drawback is that the output png are with file name like "filename.mp4.png". so my question is how can I rewrite the code so that there are no .mp4 in the output png file?

```
for %%A IN (*.mp4) DO ffmpeg -i "%%A" -vf "select=gte(n\,300)" -vframes 1 "%%A.png"
```

Comment: Welcome on SuperUser. Take your time to check the answer you received and to give us a feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It is possible to find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15567809/batch-extract-path-and-filename-from-a-variable) <sup>[[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15567809/batch-extract-path-and-filename-from-a-variable)]</sup>  that `%%~n` should give you the filename with no extension.

Try if it works

```
for %%A IN (*.mp4) DO ffmpeg -i "%%A" -vf "select=gte(n\,300)" -vframes 1 "%%~nA.png"
```

Note: You can read more in many document on internet about the expansion rules, starting from that answer <sup>[[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15567809/batch-extract-path-and-filename-from-a-variable)]</sup> and this old `nt` guide <sup>[[2](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)]</sup>.

Comment: This is exactly what I want ,thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is parameter expansion, specifically, the substring removal. Try this:

```
for file in *.mp4; do echo ffmpeg -i "$file" -vf "select=gte(n\,300)" -vframes 1 "${file%.mp4}.png"; done
```

If you have a variable `$file`, you can use `${file%.mp4}` to output the contents, with the last `.mp4` stripped off.

Here is an article with more information: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe

EDIT: Very sorry, but I thought the tag said "BASH" instead of "batch". I wondered about the funny syntax. However, I'll leave this here for now. If nobody knows a way to do this with Windows, it's quite trivial with BASH, so perhaps you could pick up a BASH shell somewhere if there's no better alternative.

Comment: Hi, maybe you want to check the syntax of your command. It seems an hybrid between Windows and Bash. brrrr.... The Op seems to be from _that_ world... the one without wall but still in need of Windows and Gates... `;-)`.

Comment: Thanks. I had just made a note about that. The funny thing is that the line worked with the change in only the variable name and adding `done`. I didn't know that BASH would handle the uppercase like that, but it does. I modified the result to make it a bit more standard.

Comment: You're welcome. For windows 10 there is a bash shell (Ubuntu derived if I remember well). It exists `cygwin` so it is usable if he really wants. (cough.. _echo_ ..cough). :-)